# Calling unsafe method using expression trees

Tags: c#, reflection, expression-trees, unsafe

I need to call `unsafe` method that takes raw pointers.

For that I need to construct `Expression` that represents pointer to value represented by `VariableExpression` or `ParameterExpression`.

How to do that?

Comment: I think this question is very interesting, and plenty well-specified for people who could answer this. I'm gonna watch this one.

Comment: [CS1944](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546089%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) is going to be a problem I would think?

Comment: @Lloyd not at all. Thanks @ AakashM ^ why don't you make that the answer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My usual approach to `Expression` stuff is to get the C# compiler to build the `Expression` for me, with its wonderful lambda-parsing ability, then inspect what it makes in the debugger. However, with the scenario you describe, we run into a problem almost straight away:

New project, set 'Allow unsafe' on.

Method that takes raw pointers:

```
class MyClass
{
    public unsafe int MyMethod(int* p)
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Code that builds an expression:

```
class Program
{
    unsafe static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var mi = typeof (MyClass).GetMethods().First(m => m.Name == "MyMethod");

        int q = 5;

        Expression<Func<MyClass, int, int>> expr = (c, i) => c.MyMethod(&i);

    }
}
```

My intent was to run this and see what `expr` looked like in the debugger; however, when I compiled I got

> error CS1944: An expression tree may not contain an unsafe pointer operation

Reviewing [the docs for this error](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546089%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), it looks like your "need to construct Expression that represents pointer to value" can never be satisfied:

> An expression tree may not contain an unsafe pointer operation
>
> Expression trees do not support pointer types because the
>   `Expression<TDelegate>.Compile` method is only allowed to produce
>   verifiable code. See comments. [there do not appear to be any
>   comments!]
>
> To correct this error
>
> - Do not use pointer types when you are trying to create an expression tree.

Answer (score 2):

I think AakashM's answer is useful (the idea to leverage the compiler to build your expression trees) so there is no need to repeat it.

However, I don't think it is completely impossible to use pointers: If you do not dereference the pointers, you can pass them around stored in an `IntPtr`. You can use and pass around `IntPtr`s in safe code, so it should also be no problem to use them in expression trees.